# Docker container unable to resolve localhost

Tags: docker, dns, hosts

I have a docker image which I have built from scratch, rather than basing it on an existing image such as centos or ubuntu. Processes on the machine do not seem to be able to resolve `localhost` or the machine hostname, even though the mapping for both exists in `/etc/hosts`. Here's what the `/etc/hosts` file on the container (generated by docker) looks like:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.3  39b50fcb603a
```

Let's say as an example I want to use telnet (other commands fail similarly) to connect to port 80.

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

This is fine, because I'm not running anything on port 80. However, let's say I use `localhost` instead:

```
$ telnet localhost 80
telnet: localhost: Name or service not known
localhost: Unknown host
```

This doesn't make sense, because the mapping from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost` is set in `/etc/hosts`. Similarly, using the hostname of the container (set by docker) also fails:

```
$ telnet $(hostname) 80
telnet: 39b50fcb603a: Name or service not known
39b50fcb603a: Unknown host
```

Why does the `/etc/hosts` file seem to not be working?

Comment: Are you exposing any ports in your Dockerfile? Are you exposing those ports to the host when you run the image? Can you post your `Dockerfile` and `docker run` command?

Comment: I'm not building this image from a Dockerfile; I'm just building it from a tarball (I don't really want to get into the reasons for doing it this way, but it fits my use case). I don't think this has to do with exposed ports because the behavior is the same regardless of port. Also, things work when I use a centos image (which I created via the same method; just using a source tarball that contained a lot more files)

Comment: what's the output of `grep "^hosts" /etc/nsswitch.conf` ?

Comment: there is no file `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

Coming in late, but can/could you replicate with:

`getent hosts localhost` (or `getent hosts <dns name>`) ?

(you will also need to install `getent` in your scratch image, along with any runtime dependencies (check `ldd getent`)

I am not strong on the details, but AFAIU glibc's `gethostbyname` will use [NSS](https://linux.die.net/man/5/nss) as the implementation to resolve names (at least on my OS, RHEL7). Even without a `nsswitch.conf`, NSS 'plugins' `libnss_files.so` and `libnss_dns.so` appear to be the default, and so these shared objects will be attempted to be dynamically loaded at runtime. If these shared libraries can't be loaded at runtime (because they are not installed in your scratch image) name resolution will fail.

So essentially you need to also install these shared objects in your image (`libresolv.so` was also required for me, as a dynamically linked dependency of `libnss_dns.conf`). The details on how probably vary across OS's, so it isn't easy for me to immediately describe an accurate process.

You can trace specifically which shared objects are being attempted to be loaded using `strace` (with `docker run --cap-add SYS_PTRACE <image> strace <command>` ).

**Final note:**
Not to confuse with the above issue, which is dynamically loaded shared objects missing at runtime. But if you are installing dynamically linked executables into a container, [this blog post](http://blog.oddbit.com/post/2015-02-05-creating-minimal-docker-images/) describes a way of determining/installing the link time dependencies automatically (it essentially uses regexes to parse the output of `ldd`)